# Error injecting entity manager with Wicket/JPA

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, wicket

I have an app using Wicket for the presentation layer with CDI/Weld, JPA 2.0, EJB 3.1 etc. (Java EE 6) deployed on GlassFish v3.0.1.

When I try to inject an EJB into a wicket page using @EJB I get the following error: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName

When I try to inject using @Inject, I get the following error: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to convert ejbRef for ejb UserRepository to a business object of type class

I believe the problem is stemming from JPA. I am using the exact same configuration that I used with a JSF application which worked properly, so I am lost as to what the issue could be. The connection pools are set up properly and pinging correctly through GlassFish, I have included wicket-weld on the classpath and I have even tried using the old Java EE 5 wicketstuff project for wicketstuff-javaeeapi with the same results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the exception:

> Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName

It might mean it is not detecting your `persistence.xml` file.  Make sure it's in the `WEB-INF\classes\META-INF` directory.

You can verify that your app has JPA enabled by going to the Admin Console in GlassFish, go to the Applications section and see if it shows something like `[ejb, web, weld, jpa]` for your app.  If it doesn't show `jpa` then it's not finding your JPA config file.

Comment: You are my hero! Why is it different than the JSF config? Why isn't this documented better?

Answer (score 0):

Could always try to lookup the EJB via its standard "java:global" name.  That should at least let you rule out wicket as a possible source of issues and get you a little closer to a working system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already used jndi lookup to attempt to get the EJB and I got the same EMF error. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Sounds like an EJB/JPA issue and not at all related to Wicket.  If you haven't, fill the 'unitName' and 'name' attributes; @PersistenceUnit(unitName="foo") should exactly match the persistence.xml/<persistence><persistence-unit name="foo"> -- Note, you can use default rules and not specify unitName, but this can quickly bite you if another persistence unit is added to the app or persistence.xml.